R scale_y_facet with violin plot: negative log values
Assume a dataframe
n <- 100
d <- data.frame("name" = c(rep("A", n), rep("B", n)),
                "type" = rep(c("X", "Y"), 2*n), 
                "value" = c(rnorm(n, 0, 1), rbeta(n, 1, 3)))

And the following violin plot:
ggplot(d, aes(name, value, fill = type)) + 
  geom_violin(trim = F, position = dodge, na.rm = T) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1, position = dodge, na.rm = T) +
  facet_wrap(facets = ~name, scales = 'free') +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.5, "cm"))   +
  ggh4x::scale_y_facet(
    name == "B",
    trans  = "log10",
    breaks = breaks_log(),
    labels = label_log()) 

which unfortunately doesn't work, as I get the message
Warning messages:
1: In transformation$transform(x) : NaNs produced
2: In scale_facet(expr = enquo(expr), "y", ..., type = type) :
  log-10 transformation introduced infinite values.
3: In transformation$transform(x) : NaNs produced
4: In scale_facet(expr = enquo(expr), "y", ..., type = type) :
  log-10 transformation introduced infinite values.
5: In transformation$transform(x) : NaNs produced
6: In scale_facet(expr = enquo(expr), "y", ..., type = type) :
  log-10 transformation introduced infinite values.
7: In transformation$transform(x) : NaNs produced
8: In scale_facet(expr = enquo(expr), "y", ..., type = type) :
  log-10 transformation introduced infinite values.

The values fed into the log transform are strictly positive, so that's not a problem. I suppose the problem lies in the fact that only after the log transformation do I obtain negative values (the indicator for that is the limit for the y-axis starts above 0). So, I need to adjust the y-axis, or more precisely, allow breaks to take negative values. How to do that?

Are you sure about "The values fed into the log transform are strictly positive"?

@Edward I am positive.

@Edward I'm log-transforming rbeta(n, 1, 3) (name == B)

Would you prefer trans  = pseudo_log_trans(base = 10)? You may need to adjust the breaks.

The violin plot extends the data at the tails (since you did not trim), thus you may get some negative values. You can prevent the warnings by using a pseudo_log transform:
ggplot(d, aes(name, value, fill = type)) + 
  geom_violin(trim = F, position = "dodge", na.rm = T) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1, position = "dodge", na.rm = T) +
  facet_wrap(facets = ~name, scales = 'free') +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.5, "cm"))   +
  ggh4x::scale_y_facet(
    name == "B",
    #trans  = "log10",
    #breaks = breaks_log(),
    trans  = pseudo_log_trans(base = 10),
    breaks = 10^(c(-5, -1, 0)),
    labels = label_log()) 


Note that if you omit the call to violin_plot (or trim the tails), you won't get the warnings.
